# iOS native app using **custom style** google maps

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

Is it possible to create a native iOS app that uses the **custom style** google maps?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

The native mapping library in iOS SDK, Mapview, does not support styling.

You can use styling via the JS V3 API in a native app. But you have to essentially build a browser within the native app that loads the JS Map.